# Getting the error "Unable find module with ID" with Aurelia Router

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm trying to configure routes in Aurelia using aurelia-router, but it throws an error that it can't find the moduleId(route to file) of my route.

I configure my routes in two files router.js and app.js, router file only contains an array with all the routes. app file is the main file of my project.

#### Project Structure:

[image: Project structure]

#### Router.js:

```
export default [
  { route: ['', '/', 'home'], name: 'home', title: 'Inicio', layoutView: 'components/common/layout/layout.html', moduleId: 'components/home/home' }
]
```

#### App.js

```
import routes from 'router'
import {RouterConfiguration, Router} from 'aurelia-router';

export class App {

  configureRouter(config, router){
    config.options.root = '/';
    config.title = 'La Tatuadora';
    this.router = router;
    config.map(routes);
  }
}
```

#### Error

[image]

Comment: What are the contents of `home.html` and `home.js`?

Comment: I already found the solution, I'm using Webpack as bundler, webpack need a resolver to find modules, Aurelia provides `PLATFORM.moduleName("moduleId")` to resolve modules, it comes with the `aurelia-pal` package. In use it looks like this: `moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("components/home/home")`.

Comment: I regularly miss this one too. It would be good to reply to your own question and mention `PLATFORM.moduleName()`

Comment: @DanyNsg Ahh nice spot. Could you self answer this question to help others?

Answer (score 15):

Aurelia provides `PLATFORM.moduleName("moduleId")` to resolve modules, it comes with the `aurelia-pal` package.

In use it looks like this:

```
{ moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("components/home/home") }
```

Comment: Very useful answer, saved me a lot of headache.  Thanks.